# XSLT transformation and renaming node

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am procesing XML which has several different tags. I am matching tag  and copying value of tag  into new tag . I have only one problem with this xslt. What if value info does not exists in tag  that i am processing? I always get empty text tag after xslt transformation. Can this somehow be avoided, so if info tag does not exists in XML, new text tags will be removed also? Hope i was clear what is my problem. Thanks for any suggestions.

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test">
    <text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="info/text()"/>
    </text>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an additional template to handle `info` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="info"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="info">
        <text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For example, on this simple input:

```
<r>
    <test>
        <info>blah</info>
    </test>
    <test></test>
</r>
```

The following output is produced:

```
<r>
    <text>blah</text>
</r>
```

**You have provided no sample input or output** so it is very difficult to tell if this is exactly what you're looking for, but the general idea stands.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the requirement in the `match` attribute of the template: simply add a predicate testing for the presence of the text node.

```
test[info/text()]
```

The above XPath expression will only match if the `test` element has a child element named `info` with nonempty text nodes in it.

Otherwise you can also use a `xsl:if` element and test for the presence of the text node.

```
<xsl:if test="info/text()">
    <text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="info/text()"/>
    </text>
</xsl>
```